# How to stop nginx from using port 80

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm trying to update [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) using `sudo apt-get install nginx`, but it is giving me an error message related to port 80 being occupied. When I run

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80
```

I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6845/nginx      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1919/config.ru  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6845/nginx
```

Although I wasn't able to easily understand what each column means from the `--help` function, I suppose that in this example `6845` is the process ID of `nginx`. If I try to kill it using

```
sudo kill 6845
```

and run `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80` again, I see

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10130/nginx     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1919/config.ru  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10130/nginx
```

In other words, it seems like `nginx` has immediately started listening on port 80 again under a different process ID. How can I stop `nginx` from running? (I've also tried `sudo systemctl stop nginx` but to no avail).

Comment: `sudo service nginx stop`

Comment: this should be a question post on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: After `sudo service nginx stop` I still see the same process running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by going to `127.0.0.1:80` in my browser, which brought me to a [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) login page. I had forgotten that I had once installed GitLab but wasn't using it. After uninstalling GitLab, port 80 was no longer occupied.

Comment: I have same problem, I change gitlab configuration and use reverse proxy to switch gitlab from port 80 to 8081, after that Ngnix works well

Answer (score 13):

You need to **explicitly** define a `listen` parameter other than 80 for every `server` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, otherwise nginx will **silently** use port 80 by default.

Also, adjust the configuration in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Comment: This was an annoying gotcha. Thank's for this comment.

Comment: I didn't know it uses 80 port implicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Open /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Change port 80 in there to something else and save your changes

Comment: Ahh ! This is what I was looking for.